# ORA-00911: invalid character Eclipse

Tags: oracle, ora-00911

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character. I cant see any problem but eclipse get error ora-911

```
        public void create(String NAME, String DOGUM, String ADRES, String EMAIL, String PASSWORD) throws SQLException {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO UYELER (UYE_ID, UYE_ADSOYAD, UYE_DOGUM, UYE_ADRES, UYE_EMAIL, UYE_PASSWORD) VALUES (UYELER_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        stmt.setString(1, NAME);
        stmt.setString(2, DOGUM);
        stmt.setString(3, ADRES);
        stmt.setString(4, EMAIL);
        stmt.setString(5, PASSWORD);

        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();

    }
```

Comment: hocam eğer date alan kullandıysan ki üye doğum date alan gibi duruyor onda hata olabilir. TAbloda Üye doğum date mi tutuluyor?

Comment: You typically get that if you include a `;` **in** the SQL string for the PreparedStatement. Are you showing us **exactly** the same code that generates the error, or some stripped down version?

Comment: Aynen benımde aklıma o geldı ama kontrol ettıgımde uye_dogum da varchar2 olarak tutuluyor

Comment: ";" deneyebilirsin ama aşağıda cevapta yazdığım gibi manuel bir şey yazabilir misin dogum alanına

Comment: dediğin gibiymiş hocam tesekkür ederim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems about date format. If your `dogum` column is date so you cant set it as `string`. If it is string so check your data. You can set it manually for test like "20180328". If it dont give any error the problem is on your data

Comment: Thanks for answer,ı change and problem was gone